# frisby: response data extraction and conditional execution

Tags: rest, testing, automation, frisby.js

I'm trying to use frisby to do some testing or automation.

Say I have 2 requests that needs to be executed one after another. However, the first request creates a resource and returns it's URI in the header:

```
POST /resource

201 
Location: /resource/123
```

So the way the second call is made depends on the response header of the first one. `afterJSON()` looks promising but it doesn't seem to handle header. Documentation seems quite short and doesn't mention this. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.after((res) -> ...` this will allow you to check response, which will contain headers that you are looking for. Firstly print `console.log(res)` the response to check if such header exist there and then you can make some operations on it by using: `res.headers.theOneThatYouWouldLikeToUse`

Comment: @lang2: Was this solution helpful ? Did you have a chance to try it ?